# Strange “java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError” in Eclipse

Tags: java, java-me

i am testing a J2me project when i run it is giving `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cdac/securitycore/storage/StorageBridge`. I had included a jar file which contains `StorageBridge.class` even i checked the class path also
my jar file compiled at 1.5 compilence
& my application is building with 1.3 compilence is this the reason for creating a problem

Comment: please add some code, that would be great and we can advice you then..!!

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cdac/securitycore/storage/StorageBridge
 at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletState.createMIDlet(+29)
 at com.sun.midp.midlet.Scheduler.schedule(+52)
 at com.sun.midp.main.Main.runLocalClass(+28)
 at com.sun.midp.main.Main.main(+80)
Execution completed.
3401700 bytecodes executed
26 thread switches
1668 classes in the system (including system classes)
17641 dynamic objects allocated (532072 bytes)
3 garbage collections (455896 bytes collected)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you did not include the .jar correctly. Right click on your project and go to Build Path->Configure Build Path->Add external .jar.  Hope that helps.

Comment: my jar file was compiled at 1.5 compilence
& my application was build with 1.3 compilence

Comment: The source and target levels are complelely irrelevant to this problem, unless there is more to the stack trace than you have revealed so far.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once. It took me hours to figure it out...

From what I remember, Eclipse kind of "has" 2 classpaths: a compile classpath and a runtime classpath. I don't remember where exactly to access both, but I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in the project's properties. Make sure that your JAR file is added to both of them.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cdac/securitycore/storage/StorageBridge. I had included a jar file which contains StorageBridge.class

But did it contain it as `org/cdac/securitycore/storage/StorageBridge.class`? and does that class contain the statement `package org.cdac.securitycore.storage;`? Getting either of whose wrong will cause this exception.

Comment: yes StorageBridge.class is present in jar file
class also contains the package

my new doubt is that my jar file was compiled at 1.5 compilence & my application was build with 1.3 compilence
wether it would be the problem

Comment: Just repeating that it is 'present' doesn't tell us anything. You haven't clarified whether both the conditions I specified are met. If it was a 1.5/1.3 problem you would get a different exception.

Comment: yes sir
my jar contains org/cdac/securitycore/storageBridge.class
and StorageBridge.java contains package org.cdac.securitycore.storage

Comment: If what you say is true you have an uppercase/lowercase problem. I suggest you build the SR file using your DE or Maven or Ant or something that knows how to do it correctly,

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding the jars by to the classpath in the following TWO ways:

`(you_project) > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs...`

AND (This is what fixed it for me)

`Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations > Classpath > User Entries > Add External JARs...`