# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with referenced library

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I searched for a solution for some hours now and, up to this point, not one of the given solutions in here has helped me. Maybe that is because I'm kind of a newbie with Eclipse and Java, but bear with me.

My problem is as follows:
I have got a class from my professor called Grid. One function of Grid is to create Grid with "Grid.create(int columnNumber, int rowNumber). I have stored the class in a folder on my desktop, with the path "Desktop/classes/lec/utils/Grid.class" (I created the folders like it was said in another thread). 
I imported the folder with "Properties -> Build Path -> Libraries -> Add external folder". I also gave the import line "import lec.utils.*;" and Eclipse shows no error with all of this. But everytime I want to use Grid.create(a,b), it shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Grid
at Aufgaben.sudoku.main(sudoku.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Grid
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

My code is as follows:

```
package Aufgaben;

import lec.utils.*;

public class sudoku {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Grid.create(9, 9);

    }
}
```

And my sidebar looks like this:

[my sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Irw.png)

If there is any other information you need, please let me know.

Edit:

[Order and Export tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUUEW.png)

Comment: can you check if your `code` folder is also marked for export in build path?  That can be configured on "Order and export", next to "Libraries"

Comment: you received .java or .class file?

Comment: For Grid, I have both actually. But there are two other classes, called "In" and "Out" I also received and these are only .class files.

Comment: Does eclipse add `Grid.class` automatically to the classpath at runtime? For me the problem seems to be that your compiler accept the .class file but the JRE can't found the .class file in classpath...

Comment: I get what you mean, vaguely. Is there some way I can check if Eclipse adds it to the classpath?

Comment: I've not really any experience with eclipse but I found this in another thread, they deals with a jar file, but it could be the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454422/strange-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse take a look specially at the last post

Comment: When you say "I imported the folder", exactly *which* folder? It should be Desktop/classes.

Comment: Yes, that's the one I imported.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get a ClassNotFoundException if the class has a static initializer that throws an exception. Such an exception would prevent the class from being loaded into the JVM. The program gets a ClassNotFoundException when the program tries to reference it. I'm not sure if that is what is happening but there is an easy way to find out.

Replace the "Grid.create(9, 9);" with "Class myclass = Grid.class;" and see if that runs. If it does, then you know your Eclipse setup is correct and the problem is with the class itself and not your setup.